# Is there is a way can hide the column in a Oracle View pivot when the whole column are 0 or null?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view, pivot

So in Oracle DB I run this query:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    WHSE,
    OLNTYPE,
    zone,
    LOCNID,
    COUNT(LOCN_BRCD) AS TOTLOCNS
    FROM IC_MST_NUTSANDBOLTS
    GROUP BY WHSE,
             OLNTYPE,
             ZONE,
             LOCNID
    ORDER BY OLNTYPE
                ) c1
PIVOT(
    COUNT(LOCNID)
    FOR (ZONE) IN
(null,
'G2',
'H2',
'P2',
'F2',
'DA',
'P3',
'A1',
'H5',
'C1',
'F1',
'P1',
'FR',
'D1',
'F3',
'G3',
'MP',
'R1',
'H1',
'H6',
'G5',
'G1',
'M1',
'B1'));
```

and here is the query result:

[image]
I want to create a view on this, but as a result some column are entirly 0 values.

So is there is a way can hide a column from this, or not getting show up if the whole column are 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The same question was answered here [Hide column if any value is null or zero via proc
>
>   sql or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6484/hide-column-if-any-value-is-null-or-zero-via-proc-sql-or-view)

You can't hide a column dynamically unless you use dynamic SQL. 
This quickly gets complicated: what if the zeros are in different columns on different rows? What should the output be

If the zeros/nulls are in the same column, then you can "hide" a column by not selecting it.

Comment: You cannot do what you want with a query, at least not without a very difficult dynamic query. But you seem to be using SQL Developer and you can do what you want in the result grid.  Right click in the title area above the result columns. This will bring up a dialog option bow, Click Columns... You can select to hide hide or displays the columns as you choose.  Downside, it is a column choice not a filter. You must provide the filtering; by knowing the column contents